# laravel version of sql (select where 1stCondition and ( 2nd)condition or 3rd_condition)

Tags: sql, laravel

I need help with translation from SQL to Laravel

```
select id, car 
  from car 
 where wheel_count>4 
   and (color in (select color from pearl_color) or color in (select color from metallic_color))
```

Comment: what you are expecting? you want the eloquent query builder code?

Comment: hello @SandeepSudhakaran: yes, I need that, but seems like I solved it 
DB::table('car')->where('wheel_count','>',4)->whereIn('color',['pearl_color','metallic_color''])->get();